# Implementing Haskell's `take` function using `foldl`

Tags: list, haskell, fold, foldleft

Implementing Haskell's `take` and `drop` functions using `foldl`.

Any suggestions on how to implement take and drop functions using `foldl` ??

```
take x ls = foldl ???

drop x ls = foldl ???
```

i've tried these but it's showing errors:

```
myFunc :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
myFunc n list = foldl func [] list
    where 
    func x y | (length y) > n = x : y 
             | otherwise      = y
```

ERROR PRODUCED :

```
*** Expression : foldl func [] list
*** Term : func
*** Type : a -> [a] -> [a]
*** Does not match : [a] -> [a] -> [a]
*** Because : unification would give infinite type
```

Comment: What errors? Your code has indentation issues, so I don't know if your errors are because of that, or because of the types. **Always write your errors in your question**.

Comment: i have added the error produced, please revise. thank you

Comment: You have the parameters to `func` the wrong way round.

Comment: And on closer look, if you correct that then your function will build the list back-to-front. It would really be much more natural to use `foldr` here (as it usually is in Haskell). [Another small problem, the inequality should be `>= n`]

Answer (score 5):

Can't be done.

Left fold necessarily diverges on infinite lists, but `take n` does not. This is so because left fold is tail recursive, so it must scan through the whole input list before it can start the processing.

With the right fold, it's

```
ntake :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
ntake 0 _  = []
ntake n xs = foldr g z xs 0
    where
    g x r i | i>=n      = []
            | otherwise = x : r (i+1)
    z _ = []

ndrop :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
ndrop 0 xs = xs
ndrop n xs = foldr g z xs 0 xs
    where
    g x r i xs@(_:t) | i>=n      = xs
                     | otherwise = r (i+1) t
    z _ _ = []
```

`ndrop` implements a *paramorphism* nicely and faithfully, up to the order of arguments to the reducer function `g`, giving it access to both the current element `x` and the current list node `xs` (such that `xs == (x:t)`) as well as the recursive result `r`. A *catamorphism's* reducer has access only to `x` and `r`.

Folds usually encode catamorphisms, but this shows that right fold can be used to code up a paramorphism just as well. It's *universal* that way. I think it is beautiful.

As for the type error, to fix it just switch the arguments to your `func`:

```
       func y x | ..... = .......
```

The accumulator in the *left* fold comes as the *first* argument to the reducer function.

---

If you *really* want it done with the left fold, and if you're *really* sure the lists are finite, two options:

```
ltake n xs = post $ foldl' g (0,id) xs
    where
    g (i,f) x | i < n = (i+1, f . (x:))
              | otherwise = (i,f)
    post (_,f) = f []

rltake n xs = foldl' g id xs r n
    where
    g acc x = acc . f x
    f x r i | i > 0 = x : r (i-1)
            | otherwise = []
    r _ = []
```

The first counts from the left straight up, potentially stopping assembling the prefix in the middle of the full list traversal that it does carry to the end nevertheless, being a left fold.

The second also traverses the list in full turning it into a right fold which *then* gets to work counting down from the left again, being able to actually stop working as soon as the prefix is assembled.

Implementing `drop` this way is bound to be (?) even clunkier. Could be a nice exercise.

Comment: interesting! but what if we assume the list is finite for now ? can it be done ? Thanks

Comment: Is `ndrop` meant to call `drop` like that?

Comment: @WillNess, yeah, isn't the whole point to *implement* drop, not to use it?

Comment: @dfeuer right; already switched to `tail`. :) I could argue that `drop 1` is not `drop n`, but I won't. :) was just being superstitious, `tail` of course is safe to use there by construction. (could use lazy pattern just as well...)

Comment: I just saw how disgusting that is. Folds just aren't the right tools for `drop`. Better to drive a nail in with a screwdriver than drive a screw in with a hammer. Take the efficiency loss and rebuild the whole list if you have no choice. `tail` isn't a real thing, unless you're doing something bizarre like the `MonadFix []` instance.

Comment: @dfeuer you're referring to `ntake`, or the new additions? *paramorphism* is the natural fit for drop, and it's easy to emulate either as cata over explicit `tails`, or with the repeated `tail` like I did. paramorphisms are nice too. :)

Comment: Yes, a paramorphism is the right tool. But pretending you're using a catamorphism like that seems like a cheat.

Answer (score 3):

I note that you never specified the fold had to be over the supplied list.  So, one approach that meets the *letter* of your question, though probably not the spirit, is:

```
sillytake :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
sillytake n xs = foldl go (const []) [1..n] xs
  where go f _ (x:xs) = x : f xs
        go _ _ []     = []

sillydrop :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
sillydrop n xs = foldl go id [1..n] xs
  where go f _ (_:xs) = f xs
        go _ _ []     = []
```

These each use left folds, but over the list of numbers `[1..n]` -- the numbers themselves are ignored, and the list is just used for its length to build a custom `take n` or `drop n` function for the given `n`.  This function is then applied to the original supplied list `xs`.

These versions work fine on infinite lists:

```
> sillytake 5 $ sillydrop 5 $ [1..]
[6,7,8,9,10]
```

Comment: this reminds me of Lisp macros: it builds a function first -- because it is a *left* fold -- then applies it. Usually it is a right fold that is applied to extra arguments, I think. Interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Will Ness showed a nice way to implement *`take`* with `foldr`. The least repulsive way to implement *`drop`* with `foldr` is this:

```
drop n0 xs0 = foldr go stop xs0 n0
  where
    stop _ = []
    go x r n
      | n <= 0 = x : r 0
      | otherwise = r (n - 1)
```

Take the efficiency loss and rebuild the whole list if you have no choice! Better to drive a nail in with a screwdriver than drive a screw in with a hammer.

Both ways are horrible. But this one helps you understand how folds can be used to structure functions and what their *limits* are.

Folds just aren't the right tools for implementing `drop`; a *paramorphism* is the right tool.

Comment: I guess our views on this are diametrically opposed. for me, the tail absolutely *must* be shared. My feeling is that *this* is "cheating". :) I'm retracing a *finite* prefix; you're rebuilding a potentially *infinite* suffix. Do several such drops in a row and you're inching ever closer to a quadratic behavior. I dislike it strongly.

Comment: It's horrible either way. But one way helps the OP understand how folds can be used to structure functions and what their limits are, while the other is just an ugly kluge with nothing to say for itself.

Comment: well, I like it; I've added more explanations to my answer. Essentially, it *is* a paramorphism; end of story. YMMV.

Comment: @WillNess, this is clearly a matter of didactic taste. I hope we can agree to disagree.

Comment: Of course, exactly what I meant (by YMMV). the dv is of course not mine, too; I checked the times -- all three votes (on the three answers) where given within a minute or so. someone felt strong agreement with my *take* on this for some reason. :) (I'm glad to have this chance to clear this out).

Comment: @WillNess, nice edit. That captures a lot of the good from our argument.

Answer (score 0):

You are not too far. Here are a pair of fixes.

First, note that `func` is passed the accumulator first (i.e. a list of `a`, in your case) and then the list element (an `a`). So, you need to swap the order of the arguments of `func`.

Then, if we want to mimic `take`, we need to add `x` when the `length y` is *less* than `n`, not greater!

So we get

```
myFunc :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
myFunc n list = foldl func [] list
    where 
    func y x | (length y) < n = x : y 
             | otherwise      = y
```

Test:

```
> myFunc 5 [1..10]
[5,4,3,2,1]
```

As you can see, this is reversing the string. This is because we add `x` at the front (`x:y`) instead of at the back (`y++[x]`). Or, alternatively, one could use `reverse (foldl ....)` to fix the order at the end.

Also, since `foldl` always scans the whole input list, `myFunc 3 [1..1000000000]` will take a lot of time, and `myFunc 3 [1..]` will fail to terminate. Using `foldr` would be much better.

`drop` is more tricky to do. I don't think you can easily do that without some post-processing like `myFunc n xs = fst (foldl ...)` or making `foldl` return a function which you immediately call (which is also a kind of post-processing).

Comment: Awesome, Thank you very much!!

Comment: Checking the length over and over is sure to make it quadratic anyway.

Comment: @dfeuer I indeed missed that. Thanks.